# How to add a library to Gradle build in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I want to add the following library to the Gradle build of my project. The library that I want to add is : `signal-protocol-java-2.8.1.jar` that I have downloaded. How can I add it in the Gradle build, so that I import the classes included in the .jar it in the java classes that I am developing ?

Here is my `build.gradle` file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter {
            content {
                includeVersion 'org.jetbrains.trove4j', 'trove4j', '20160824'
                includeGroupByRegex "com\\.archinamon.*"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.14'
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha09"
    }
}


ext {
    BUILD_TOOL_VERSION = '30.0.2'

    COMPILE_SDK = 30
    TARGET_SDK  = 30
    MINIMUM_SDK = 19

    JAVA_VERSION = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

wrapper {
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    ext.lib_signal_service_version_number   = "2.15.3"
    ext.lib_signal_service_group_info       = "org.whispersystems"
    ext.lib_signal_metadata_version         = "0.1.2"

    if (JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
        allprojects {
            tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
                options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
            }
        }
    }
}

task qa {
    group 'Verification'
    description 'Quality Assurance. Run before pushing.'
    dependsOn ':Signal-Android:testPlayProdReleaseUnitTest',
            ':Signal-Android:lintPlayProdRelease',
            ':libsignal-service:test',
            ':Signal-Android:assemblePlayProdDebug'
}
```

Comment: If you have it as a module in your project, use `implemenation project(":...")`, where `...` is the name of your module. Put that in the `dependencies` closure of your app module. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your module-level `build.gradle` (the one you've posted is project-level). It's typically in the "app" folder of your project. Find there `dependencies` block and add this line:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    ...
}
```

Then create a folder "libs" near this gradle file and put your .jar library there. Sync the project with Gradle.

Comment: Which .gradle library should I put in the "libs" folder? @alexal1

Comment: Messed up words, sorry! Put your .jar library into the "libs" folder. Edited the post too

Comment: Thanks, I did it. I actually had a question, I want to access the classes inside the ".jar" from another folder. How can I access them? @alexal1

Comment: According to your question you want to "import the classes included in the .jar it in the java classes that I am developing", is that true? Then do what I said and sync project with Gradle in Android Studio. Then you'll be able to import them.

Comment: Thanks ,  I added it. 
I have another question if you could help me. Do you know how can I exclude some files included in the library that I added? There is already another version of the library that exists in the project, and I have errors about duplication :( @alexal1

Comment: `dependencies {
    implementation('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4') {
        exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
    }
}`
from Gradle docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html